# Noun compound: gerund + noun ("he couldn't find a job acting" / "an acting job")

Tags: word-order

Is `job acting` correct in the following text:

> When Hans's father died, he was only 11 years old. When he was 14 he
>   set out for Copenhagen, the biggest city in Denmark, to make his
>   fortune. There he was often hungry and homeless. He wanted to be an
>   actor, and could not find a *job acting*.

Source: [Who Exactly is Hans Christian Andersen?](http://ezinearticles.com/?Who-Exactly-is-Hans-Christian-Andersen?&id=4878893)

Shouldn't it be `acting job`?

Comment: "A job acting" and "an acting job" are both grammatically correct. I prefer "a job acting". (The change I would make to that sentence is to replace "and" with "but".)

Comment: As @nnnnnn says, both are correct. Araucaria has provided [a link to a Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="a++job+acting"&biw=360&bih=567&tbm=bks&prmd=vin&ei=j945V7e1H8SHmQHypruYCw&start=10&sa=N&dpr=2)  for *a job acting* (I started it on page 2 to bypass some false positives. I also agree with nnnnnn that *a job acting* sounds better (is more idiomatic) than *an acting job* here.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=An+acting+job%2C+a+job+acting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAn%20acting%20job%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20job%20acting%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

According to grammar, you can find something doing something.

Besides, according to Ngram, both "a job acting" and "an acting job" are correct, but the former is more idiomatic than the latter.

Comment: Your suggestion "He couldn't find a job *for* acting" isn't right. "A job *involving* acting" would be fine. But I prefer the sound of "a job acting".

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=An+acting+job%2C+a+job+acting&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAn%20acting%20job%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20job%20acting%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.  The difference is in emphasis, which falls at the end.

If I say "I couldn't find a brown dog" it means that I was looking at dogs generally. If I say "I couldn't find a dog that was brown," it emphasizes that a *brown* one was especially important.  So, in the first case I might have brought home a non-brown dog, but in the second it's more likely that I didn't bring home any, since its brown-ness was so important.